# Have to tap twice to select an UITableViewCell after dragging with UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a small `320x144`viewcontroller named `SubViewController.h` which has a UITableView in it with 3 cells with a single section. I have made the tableView unscrollable and also put some shadow effect behind the tableView by grace of `CALayer`.

In another viewcontroller named as MainViewController.m i have added `SubViewController.h` as a subview to this `MainViewController`. Using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` i have successfully able to drag the SubViewContoller anywhere i want.

I make this subView visible with a `UIBarButtonItem`. And after selecting a cell in the tableView of the subview i made it disappear from  main view with some animation.

Everything works fine.

But when i drag the subview and then try to select one cell i have to tap the cell twice. In first tap nothing actually happens except the cell turns blue(like it happens normally when you select a cell in tableView) but does not go Hidden. If i tap again then it will go hidden.

Without dragging the subview i can select one cell with a single touch and also the view goes hidden.

I have written the code for hiding the subview in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method of the subview. And I have checked this method is not called when i select first time after dragging the subview.In the second tap or touch it is called though. And again if the user moves the subview again same problem occurs.

Surely some property of the subview got changed after dragging which i cant able to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    NSUInteger tapCount = [touch tapCount];

    switch (tapCount) {
        case 1:
            [self performSelector:@selector(singleTapMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:.4];
            break;
        case 2:
            [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(singleTapMethod) object:nil];
            [self performSelector:@selector(doubleTapMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:.4];
            break;
. . .
}
```

Comment: this is not what i expected. I am sure I have to write something when UIGestureRecocgnizerStateEnded..

Answer (score 0):

First when u want your subView to be shown ,that is on click of your UIBarButtonItem:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick
{
        //setup ur view dynamically as you like//
        PSview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 310,450)];
        PSview.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        PSview.alpha=0.8;
        [PSview.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
        [PSview.layer setBorderWidth: 3.0];


    PSview.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    PSview.clipsToBounds=YES;
    [PSview.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [PSview.layer setBorderWidth: 3.0];

    [PSview addSubview:subView];
    [self.view addSubview:PSview];
```

}

then later :

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
//since there are two tables in one view, you can differentiate them using if()
     if(tableView==subView) 
        {
            // ...ur code . ..
            // write your code what needs to happen when you click a row of your subView.
            [PSview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    if(tableView==mainView)
       {
      // write your code , what happens when user clicks row of the main table
       }
    }
```

Comment: will you please elaborate your view??